# What is the best backup solution for SharePoint 2013 enterprise?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, backup

The native MS backup of sharepoint lasts 90 days, and can be corrupted if anyone syncs in a bad file and that gets backed up.

I am looking for a solution that can back up site collections for longer than 90 days and give more customization options.

Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

You can always backup content databases. This is often more reliable than SharePoint site collection backup.

[More info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428327.aspx)